# Simple javascript function - if statement not triggering?

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I have an overly simple javascript function and I can't figure out why the if statement isn't triggering in it:

```
var theChange;
function showChangeBox(theChange) {
    if (theChange == 'fName') {
        document.getElementById('userPanelChangeBox').innerHTML = 'Some HTML';
        }
    document.getElementById('userPanelChangeBox').style.display = "block";
    return;
    }
```

It's called by an onClick:

```
<a href="#" onclick="showChangeBox('fname');">Click to Change</a>
```

Simple, right?  I've done a bunch of these before, I can't figure out why this isn't working, I'm sure it's something ridiculous that I missed but after staring at it for 20 minutes, my tunnel vision might be preventing me from seeing the error.

It's triggering the change to the display, but I know it isn't going to the if because if I put an alert in it, I get no alert.  Grrr.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a matter of case, `"fName"` != `"fname"`.

Comment: *&#(@$ - I knew it was something stupid like that, thank you for saving the rest of the hair on my head.  Odd how we don't see things we know to look for after we've gone on tilt.